# Unable to Stop Windows Service Hosting Web API

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting

I am running web api 2 as a self hosted in a windows service, during the stop I call 
`this.webApp.Dispose();`

However this looks not enough to gracefully stopping the service as I get the following exception:

```
Failed to stop service. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://+:8080/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func`2 app, IDictionary`2 properties)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, Cu...
```

So the only way to stop the service is to get PID for that service and then use kill-process.

Is there a way to gracefully stop the service, knowing that I am not running a long task on stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that during `stop()` windows service I was actually calling `OnStart` event which would start the web api rather than stopping it.